# Create CSV from result of a for Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, export-to-csv, wikidata

I'm using Wikidata query service to obtain values and this is the code:

```
pip install sparqlwrapper

import sys
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

endpoint_url = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"

query = """#List of organizations 

SELECT ?org ?orgLabel
WHERE
{
  ?org wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453. #instance of organizations
  ?org wdt:P17 wd:Q96. #Mexico country

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}"""


def get_results(endpoint_url, query):
    user_agent = "WDQS-example Python/%s.%s" % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])
    # TODO adjust user agent; see https://w.wiki/CX6
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(endpoint_url, agent=user_agent)
    sparql.setQuery(query)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    return sparql.query().convert()

results = get_results(endpoint_url, query)

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result)
```

This code give me the data that I need but I'm having problems trying to get this information with this line:

```
results.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

with this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I import pandas and numpy to do it, but I'm still with problems so I would like to know how to put this results in a format to create my csv file with the data obtained.

Here you have some screenshots.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), that is a python data structure which you can't invoke a method `to_csv` on.

For safely storing a csv from a python dictionary you can use external libraries (see also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) on python.org).

The specific solution depends on which (meta)data you exactly want to export. In the following I assume that you want to store the `value` for `org` and `orgLabel`.

```py
import csv
bindings = results['results']['bindings']
sparqlVars = ['org', 'orgLabel']
metaAttribute = 'value'
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile :
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=sparqlVars)
    writer.writeheader()
    for b in bindings :
        writer.writerow({var:b[var][metaAttribute] for var in sparqlVars})
```

And the output is:

```
org,orgLabel
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099,"Grupo Televisa, owner of TelevisaUnivision"
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q429380,Aeropuertos y Servicios Auxiliares
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q482267,América Móvil
...
```

Comment: That works exactly as I need it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a committer of
https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyLoDStorage

i am going to point out that the SPARQL class of pyLodStorage is explicitly there to make conversion to other formats simple.

```sh
pip install pyLodStorage
```

```sh
sparqlquery --query 'SELECT ?org ?orgLabel
WHERE
{
  ?org wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453. #instance of organizations
  ?org wdt:P17 wd:Q96. #Mexico country

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}' --format csv
```

result:

```
"org","orgLabel"
"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099","Grupo Televisa, owner of TelevisaUnivision"
"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q482267","América Móvil"
"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q515411","Q515411"
"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q521673","Grupo Modelo"
```

for course you can get the same result directly via the python APIs:

```py
from lodstorage.sparql import SPARQL
from lodstorage.csv import CSV

sparqlQuery="""SELECT ?org ?orgLabel
WHERE
{
  ?org wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453. #instance of organizations
  ?org wdt:P17 wd:Q96. #Mexico country

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}"""
        sparql=SPARQL("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
        qlod=sparql.queryAsListOfDicts(sparqlQuery)
        csv=CSV.toCSV(qlod)
        print(csv)
```